# C# Winforms - Issue reading a csv file

Tags: c#, csv, streamreader

I have looked at all of the csv reading examples I can find and I'm not quite sure where I'm going wrong with this one.

I am fairly new to C# but loving it so far!

Anyway heres the code that works great *most* of the time (you can see by the comments I have tried a bunch of different options in the read):

```
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(csvFileToImport);
                while (sr.EndOfStream != true)
                {
                    string line = sr.ReadLine();
                //string[] value = line.Split(new string[] { "\",\"" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
                //string[] value = line.Split(new string[] {","}, StringSplitOptions.None);
                //string[] value = line.Split(new string[] { "(?=(?:[^']*'[^']*')*[^']*$)" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
                //string[] value = line.Split(new string[] { "," }, StringSplitOptions.None);
                string[] value = Regex.Split(line, @"\s|[,]");

                StockItem si = new StockItem();
                    switch (stockFile.Supplier)
                    {
                        case "Leader":
                            si.Supplier = stockFile.Supplier;
                            si.Category = value[2].Replace("'", "''");
                            si.StockCode = value[11].Replace("'", "''");
                            si.Cost = Convert.ToDecimal(value[7]);
                            si.Description = value[4].Replace("'", "''");
                            si.Image = value[9].Replace("'", "''");
                            si.Manufacturer = value[10].Replace("'", "''");
                            si.Sell = Convert.ToDecimal(value[8]);
                            si.StockAdelaide = value[17].Replace("'", "''");
                            si.StockBrisbane = value[18].Replace("'", "''");

                            si.StockMelbourne = value[19].Replace("'", "''");
                            si.StockPerth = value[20].Replace("'", "''");
                            si.StockSydney = value[21].Replace("'", "''");
                            si.Subcategory = value[3].Replace("'", "''");

                            //Add line into db
                            string sql = "insert into Stock (Supplier, StockCode, Manufacturer, Category, Subcategory, Description, Cost, Sell, Image, StockPerth, StockAdelaide, StockSydney, StockBrisbane, StockMelbourne) values ('" + si.Supplier + "', '" + si.StockCode + "', '" + si.Manufacturer + "', '" + si.Category + "', '" + si.Subcategory + "', '" + si.Description + "', " + si.Cost + ", " + si.Sell + ", '" + si.Image + "', '" + si.StockPerth + "', '" + si.StockAdelaide + "', '" + si.StockSydney + "', '" + si.StockBrisbane + "', '" + si.StockMelbourne + "')";
                            cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, cn);
                            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                            break;
                        default:
                            break;
                    }
                }
                success = true;
                cn.Close();
```

I have linked to a 1 line csv file which doesnt read correctly if anyone wouyld be so good as to have a look I would be really greatful!

Thanks in advance, and also feel free to point out any general code I could improve... I'm sure there is lots to improve on.

Thanks again :)

CSV Link: https://www.dropbox.com/s/nnaruu0twds3wrl/csv_error.csv?dl=0

UPDATE:

Apologies for the lack of clarity, as I am reading the file I get the following error:

System.FormatException: 'Input string was not in a correct format.'

The line reads as:

```
"MECMD4VL2X426,ME,Memory,DDR-4 (Desktop),Corsair Vengeance LPX 8GB (2x4GB) DDR4 2666MHz C16 Desktop Gaming Memory Black,\"Corsair 8GB (2x4GB) DDR4 2666MHz Vengeance LPX Black"
```

When I query the array it shows the values as:

```
value[0] "MECMD4VL2X426"
value[1] "ME"
value[2] "Memory"
value[3] "DDR-4"
value[4] "(Desktop)"
value[5] "Corsair"
value[6] "Vengeance"
value[7] "LPX"
...
```

It appears to get stuck on the brackets (that should be read into value[3]), and then starts seperating on space instead of comma.

Im happy to use a 3rd party csv reader if needed, however I'd love to understand how it works myself.

Comment: it "doesn't read correctly" - how? Do you get wrong columns, skip lines, get an exception? Please specify.

Comment: Also, don't try and escape quotes to build a sql command, but use parameters instead.

Comment: I will recommend reading [ask] and specially [mre]. Your question must be self contains and the problematic csv reduce to it's bare minimum. I will also recommend splitting the code in function that way you could test the different part: Read the file, Map csv to item, Insert. Here you may have an issue with new line in quoted field. The Csv is correct you are just reading the line one by one, so you don't get the end of the field that span on 19 lines

Comment: The very long description field in your CSV file contains many `,` characters in the text. Your parsing produces an array of information that you don't expect. `value[7]` is not decimal for example. You need to revise your csv reading approach.

Comment: the simpliest solution would be Imo to use a 3rd party like [CSV helper](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/). you just have to define the class and 3 lines of code should be enought to do the whole thing.

Comment: "I have linked to a 1 line csv file " if it's only 1 line then please post it simply. We don't like to download things from unknown sources.

Comment: shouldn't `"DDR-4 (Desktop)"` be only 1 value? why are you splitting also by space?

Comment: Mong Zhu - thats correct, I dont want to be splitting by space. I'm going to give Drag and Drop's solution a go - thanks for the help everyone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading the csv you use `string line = sr.ReadLine();` but the [RFC 4180](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180) ,
2.6 tell us that a field containig multiples lines should be encapsuled with DQuote `"`.

So reading the file line by line will be an issue if those multiples lines field exist in your document.
I would drop the hand made regex and the `ReadLine` and use a more robust parser like [CSV Helper](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/).

Then define the object you want to get from the CSV.

```
public class Leader
{
    public string LongColumn6 { get; set; }

    public string Supplier { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }
    public string StockCode { get; set; }
    public Decimal Cost { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Image { get; set; }
    public string Manufacturer { get; set; }
    public Decimal Sell { get; set; }
    public string StockAdelaide { get; set; }
    public string StockBrisbane { get; set; }
    public string StockMelbourne { get; set; }
    public string StockPerth { get; set; }
    public string StockSydney { get; set; }
    public string Subcategory { get; set; }
}
```

And it's respective mapper: column & is Foo properties etc..

```
public sealed class LeaderMap : ClassMap<Leader>
{
    public LeaderMap()
    {
        Map(m => m.LongColumn6).Index(5); // the column that cause the issue

        //complete the List
        Map(m => m.Category).Index(2);
        Map(m => m.StockCode).Index(11);
        Map(m => m.Cost).Index(7);
        Map(m => m.Description).Index(4);
    }
}
```

Then the reading is simple:

```
using (var csvReader = new CsvReader(reader,  CultureInfo.InvariantCulture ))
{   
    csvReader.Configuration.HasHeaderRecord = false;
    csvReader.Configuration.RegisterClassMap<LeaderMap>();
    records = csvReader.GetRecords<Leader>().ToList();
}
```

Note that in this [live demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/vK83GV) .
I used a StringReader in order to mimic a file Reader.
You can use a file reader and pass it your path.

Comment: Thanks so much for the comprehensive answer - I will give this a go and report back :)